# talk to tethered hardware from iOS

Tags: ios

What options do I have in iOS (6 or later) to talk to custom hardware that is connected to the device through a cable without jailbreaking? (think USB, RS232, Arduino ...)

I am new to iOS development and I have read that there are some harsh licensing terms and restrictions in the apple ecosystem in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ , in particular iproxy. On a Linux machine I've used it to create a TCP connection over a USB-to-30-pin-connector to an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1, afaik it should still work on iOS 6. I doubt you'd get accepted to the app-store using this but if you're just making a hobby application it's probably exactly what you need.

There's also the MFi program (https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) for making more commercial hardware, but all that stuff is under NDA so you should join up and discuss things on the Apple MFi forum.

Comment: I might not be able to go into the app store, but will I be able to deploy it in-house using the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

Comment: I'm not experienced at all with the Enterprise Program but AFAIK Apple does not review apps there.

Comment: Just to clarify what actually goes into an app using iproxy, you don't actually do anything particularly naughty within the app. All you do is create a TCP connection to the loopback address. The other end of this is your Linux machine sending magical USB packets, which iproxy abstracts away from. The bit in between is Apple Undocumented Magic.

Comment: I am suprised that this also works with iPhone 5, which has this lightning connector.